Autodiscovery failure
We are using exchange web service to read emails from journaling mailbox.
We have two domain say domain1 and domain2 , with one way trust.
Domain1 can have access to domain2.
Now journaling mailbox is on domain2 and user1@domain2.com mailbox is read by user1@doamain1.com using linkedmailbox account and exchange web service api.
We are using c# code
_ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(SmtpAddress); we are using exchanges server 2014
here SmtpAddress is user1@domain2.com.
Code was working absolutely hassle free for almost more than decade. Now last month suddenly we got Autosicovery service failure. After investigation we observed that after getting windows patches, somehow writes of user1@domain1.com got vanished from journaling mailbox, it was showing sid instead of name in linkedmailbox property.
We again gave rights on linked mailbox and restarted domain controllers of domain2.
This time problem got solved.
Again this month after patches rights were gone and even after repeating the above process, we are still seeing sid of user1@domain1.com instead of its name in linkedmailbox account property.
Regards
Amit
We would like to know

How to solve sid display issue and get name displayed in linkedmailbox account propery
If anyone has encountered such issue after windows pathces

